# Check if JS API function is supported in a current browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have an example where I need to check if Safari V 5.1 supports `FileReader` function. I tried with:

```
if (typeof FileReader !== "object") { 
    alert("NA");
}
```

However now even in my other browsers which I know for a fact they support `FileReader` I get the alert displayed! So I imagine I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: alert(typeof FileReader) to see, what it is...

Comment: `if (typeof FileReader === "function")` should work.

Comment: It is function in all the browsers but some of them don't support it

Comment: What's the difference between it being a function in a browser and being supported?

Comment: function can still be a function, it just doesn't work

Comment: `if ("FileReader" in window) { ... }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

check if the function is defined or not:

have you tried the following?

```
if(typeof(window.FileReader)!="undefined"){
     //Your code if supported
}else{
     //your code if not supported
}
```

Comment: Yes and safari still returns false in first clause yet It doesn't support the function

Comment: If safari doesn't support it, the if statement should evaluate to false. so this is correct behaviour.

Comment: Why does it return `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'FileAPIProxy.swfObject.read')` then

Comment: You need to give me more information. It is not clear what you are doing. What line is giving you this error?

Comment: Nevermind the previous but I sill get the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FileReader` if I try your method

Comment: I'm running out of options here. You should try the window.FileReader but with the typeof check. so if(typeof(window.FileReader) != "undefined")

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window)

> The window property of a Window object points to the window object itself.

JS [IN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator can be used.

```js
if('FileReader' in window)
  console.log('FileReader found');
else
  console.log('FileReader not found');
```

OR using given code sample.

```js
if (!'FileReader' in window) {
  alert("NA"); // alert will show if 'FileReader' does not exists in 'window'
}
```