# How to check if Promise.any is supported by the browser

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array of promises and I am using `Promise.any` to check if anyone of them resolves. However, i notice that `Promise.any` is a recent addition and some older version of Chrome and Edge do not support it.

Is there a way to check if `Promise.any` is supported in the browser and if not display some notification to the user to upgrade.

Thanks.

Comment: `("any" in Promise)`? ... but why not use [one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-any-polyfill) of [the many](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.any) polyfills that claim to be spec compliant?

Comment: What'll you do if you figure out it's *not* supported…? Just not run your code? The practical answer here is to include a *polyfill* that makes it available on all browsers.

Comment: for example: `const anySupported = typeof Promise === "function" && typeof Promise.any === "function";`

Comment: Just for your information, https://caniuse.com/?search=Promise.any Almost all browser supports it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if JS API function is supported in a current browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653951/check-if-js-api-function-is-supported-in-a-current-browser)

Comment: [Fairly easy way without _any_ code!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any#browser_compatibility)